# From raster histogram/raster make frequency tables in Python

Tags: python, raster, histogram

Im new in programming... I would like to know, how I can get a frequency table from a rasters histograms? Or how can I generate the table from a raster?

I would like a table of the histogram showed below

[image]

Comment: Using what GIS software or Python library?

Comment: Im using jupyter notebook.. so yeah python library